# Offline caching in flutter?

Tags: flutter, offline-caching

I have some videos in AWS storage... I need to access the videos from a mobile app... I can access when there is internet connection. But if I switch to airplane mode the app is crashing. Is there a way to see the videos when you switch from online to offline mode.? Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [flutter_cache_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager)

or use [cached_video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_video_player)

> A flutter plugin that has been forked from the official video_player package except that it supports caching.

```
  CachedVideoPlayerController controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = CachedVideoPlayerController.network(
        "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4");
    controller.initialize().then((_) {
      setState(() {});
      controller.play();
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: controller.value != null && controller.value.initialized
              ? AspectRatio(
                  child: CachedVideoPlayer(controller),
                  aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
                )
              : Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                )),
    );
  }
}
```